# Get process resource by PID

Tags: php, shell, sockets, proc-open

I want to write web SSH console, and i found two problems.

What i want to do. First I want to execute `start.php` file which have following code.

```
$process = proc_open('start', array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
    1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
    2 => array("pipe", "a")
), $pipes);
```

Second i want to run `command.php` file which run command on created process in `start.php` file and get results from it.

```
$pid = 12345;
print_r(process_command('ping google.com', $pid));
```

I just want to access process (`cmd`) created in past, send command to it and get result.

Why this is problem, if i can create new process for each `command.php` execution? Because new process is new session, If i login to mysql in past `command.php` execution, in next executions i must login to mysql again, because new process not remember i was logged.

Example on windows.

1. I create new process (`cmd`) in PHP, my current directory is `C:\WebServ\`.

[image]

2. I write `cd /` command, my current directory is `C:\`.

[image]

**This is just example, i dont want only change directory, this is not problem for me.**

Problem is how to create one process and access to it in next PHP file executions - if i want remember `mysql` session for example?

1. I can create process by `proc_open` function.
2. I can get PID by `get_process_status`, but how to get process resource created before current PHP file was executed?

And next question, how to write new command to created process, if accessing to created process in past is possible?

**I dont want use PHP extensions.
But if this is required in this case, each answer will help me.**

If access to process created in other PHP executions is not possible, i want use `while(1)` to control created process at begin of PHP execution - but i hope this is not required in this case.
**Then I hope anyone know, how to write new command to created `cmd` process.**

---

### **If solution for my question is problem, i will accept answer which tell me how to send commands to `cmd.exe` process opened by `shell_exec`, and how to receive response for each command.**

Comment: How are the files getting the commands? As arguements or by including the file and calling functions/setting variables?

Comment: This is just example of code, I just want to run `cmd` process in background, send command to it and receive response.

Comment: See my updated answer please. This will read input, and send commands to `cmd` until you type `exit`

Answer (score 0):

`proc_open()` returns a **resource** type. Resources cannot be serialized so you cannot save it for later. They are freed at the end of your script execution with the exception of persistent database connections.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking now. Try this:

```
<?php
$fd = array(
0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
2 => array("file", "error.txt", "a") // stderr
);

$process = proc_open("cmd.exe", $fd, $pipes);

echo "Welcome to this interactive CMD shell. Please type your commands below\n";
while(is_resource($process) {
  $input = readline(); //Get user input
  $input .= "\n";      //Need newline to press ENTER on CMD

  if($input == "exit\n") {

    fwrite($pipes[0], $input);
    break; //End BOTH this program AND cmd
  }

 fwrite($pipes[0], $input);
}

fclose($pipes[0]);
echo file_get_stream($pipes[1]); //print all the output from CMD

//Cleanup
fclose($pipes[2]);
proc_close($process); //Should already be closed!
```

Note, you cannot get data from the child until you close its STDIN ($pipes[0]).... Meaning you cannot get the child's output until you finish sending it commands.

Answer (score 0):

What about this very naive* approach:

1) Your `start.php` script would poll a file resource, e.g. `/tmp/commands.in` for incoming commands. Of course, the script could only do this as long as your PHP setting `max_execution_time` permits so be sure to call `set_time_limit(0);` to remove the limit. If a command is found in the file, the script would execute it through its process pipe to `cmd` or `bash` or whatever is being used as the shell and write the output to `/tmp/commands.out`.

2) Your `command.php` would then write commands to `/tmp/commands.in` and read the content of `/tmp/commands.out` and display it in the browser.

*) Naive because concurrency, security and probably a lot other issues come obviously with this approach. So these issues must be dealt with by using file locks, ACLs and so on.

Comment: Executing all commends from past, in each next request to process, take to more time.