# PHP - Get input and output stream for a background process

Tags: php, sockets, stream

Suppose i've a background running process, how can I get streams for input/output/error in a similar way with proc_open and pipes?

I've read about "expect", but I haven't no idea on how to do this.

Could someone post a usefull snippet, that starting from the pid of the process, create those 3 streams?

Summary Scenario:

1) Process A started at unknow time, but is running

2) Process B, C, D etc want to write/read to/from process A -> how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088760/get-process-resource-by-pid

Comment: Checked but didn't seems to be what i'm looking for, or i'm wrong?